Discord.Net: Gateway Blocked and Task Canceled When Connecting to Voice Channel in UserVoiceStateUpdated Event
I'm developing a Discord bot using C# and the Discord.Net library. The bot joins a voice channel when a user joins the channel and leaves upon receiving a specific command. However, I'm encountering issues where the gateway gets blocked, and the connection task gets canceled, throwing a TaskCanceledException. I can get rid of the Gateway blocked error by adding _ = task.Run(async () => {} around the area causing problems, but when I do so, it introduces another error. Here is a full example of logs that happen from when the bot starts up, to when it tries to join, and finally, when it disconnects.
13:38:04 Discord     Discord.Net v3.15.3 (API v10)
13:38:04 Gateway     Connecting
13:38:05 Gateway     You're using the GuildScheduledEvents gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
13:38:05 Gateway     You're using the GuildInvites gateway intent without listening to any events related to that intent, consider removing the intent from your config.
13:38:05 Gateway     Connected
13:38:05 Gateway     Ready
[INFO] Attempting to join voice channel: Gamers 2
13:38:11 Audio #1    Connecting
13:38:11 Audio #1    Unknown OpCode (11)
13:38:11 Audio #1    Unknown OpCode (18)
13:38:11 Audio #1    Unknown OpCode (20)
13:38:11 Audio #1    Unknown OpCode (11)
13:38:11 Audio #1    Unknown OpCode (18)
13:38:11 Audio #1    Unknown OpCode (20)
13:38:26 Audio #1    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Discord.Audio.AudioClient.OnConnectingAsync()
   at Discord.ConnectionManager.ConnectAsync(CancellationTokenSource reconnectCancelToken)
   at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
13:38:26 Audio #1    Disconnecting
13:38:26 Audio #1    Disconnected
[ERROR] Error while attempting to join voice channel: Gamers 2. Exception: The operation has timed out.

I have rewritten my code multiple times to try and cut out anything extra, but I seem to end up with the same error no matter how simple my implementation. I believe it would be easy to fix if the bot were joining based on a command like the example from the Discord.Net docs:
// The command's Run Mode MUST be set to RunMode.Async, otherwise, being connected to a voice channel will block the gateway thread.
[Command("join", RunMode = RunMode.Async)] 
public async Task JoinChannel(IVoiceChannel channel = null)
{
    // Get the audio channel
    channel = channel ?? (Context.User as IGuildUser)?.VoiceChannel;
    if (channel == null) { await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("User must be in a voice channel, or a voice channel must be passed as an argument."); return; }

    // For the next step with transmitting audio, you would want to pass this Audio Client in to a service.
    var audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();
}

Here is my audio service class where I am making the call to join the channel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Audio;
using Discord.WebSocket;

public class AudioService
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, IAudioClient> _voiceConnections;

    public AudioService(DiscordSocketClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _voiceConnections = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, IAudioClient>();

        _client.UserVoiceStateUpdated += OnUserVoiceStateUpdated;
    }

    public Task OnUserVoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState oldState, SocketVoiceState newState)
    {
        // Make sure this does not block the gateway task
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // This is where the code is breaking
            await HandleUserVoiceStateUpdated(user, oldState, newState);
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task HandleUserVoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState oldState, SocketVoiceState newState)
    {
        if (user.IsBot) return;

        if (newState.VoiceChannel != null && oldState.VoiceChannel != newState.VoiceChannel)
        {
            // Asynchronously join the voice channel
            await JoinVoiceChannelWithRetry(newState.VoiceChannel, 3, 5);
        }
        else if (oldState.VoiceChannel != null && newState.VoiceChannel == null && !oldState.VoiceChannel.Users.Any(u => !u.IsBot))
        {
            // Asynchronously leave the voice channel
            await LeaveVoiceChannelAsync(oldState.VoiceChannel);
        }
    }

    public async Task JoinVoiceChannelWithRetry(IVoiceChannel channel, int maxAttempts, int delaySeconds)
    {
        int attempt = 0;
        while (attempt < maxAttempts)
        {
            try
            {
                await JoinVoiceChannelAsync(channel);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                attempt++;
                Console.WriteLine($"[RETRY] Attempt {attempt} failed for voice channel {channel.Id}: {ex.Message}");
                if (attempt < maxAttempts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"[INFO] Retrying to join voice channel {channel.Id} in {delaySeconds} seconds...");
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delaySeconds));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"[ERROR] Max retry attempts reached for voice channel {channel.Id}. Giving up.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task JoinVoiceChannelAsync(IVoiceChannel channel)
    {
        if (_voiceConnections.ContainsKey(channel.Guild.Id))
            return;

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[INFO] Attempting to join voice channel: {channel.Name}");

            // Connect asynchronously and offload the task
            var audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();
            if (_voiceConnections.TryAdd(channel.Guild.Id, audioClient))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[INFO] Successfully connected to voice channel: {channel.Name}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[ERROR] Failed to add connection to dictionary for voice channel: {channel.Name}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[ERROR] Error while attempting to join voice channel: {channel.Name}. Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task LeaveVoiceChannelAsync(IVoiceChannel channel)
    {
        if (_voiceConnections.TryRemove(channel.Guild.Id, out var client))
        {
            await client.StopAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"[INFO] Left voice channel: {channel.Name}");
        }
    }
}

The program.cs file where my services are configured is here:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandHandler _commandHandler;

    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        var services = ConfigureServices();
        _client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();
        _client.Log += LogAsync;

        string token = "HERES_MY_BOT_TOKEN";

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        await _client.StartAsync();

        _commandHandler = services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandler>();
        await _commandHandler.InstallCommandsAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private ServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        return new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<DiscordSocketClient>()
            .AddSingleton<CommandService>()
            .AddSingleton<CommandHandler>()
            .AddSingleton<AudioService>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private Task LogAsync(LogMessage log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(log.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Overall I am just confused because it seems like the issue is coming from within the channel.ConnectAsync(); method within Discord.Net. I also was wondering if there is maybe a new way to accomplish this? Most all of the documentation I have seen is from upwards of 10 years ago, which is most likely not up to date with the current way to implement this. I have other functionality I am excited to try out and get working, but I can't really do that until I get the basic joining functionality down for the bot :). Thanks in advance for your help!
